# HTTP 302 on /connect Soundcloud API

Tags: api, soundcloud

why when I go to https://soundcloud.com/connect?client_id=MY_ID&redirect_uri=http://MY/FULL/URL/&response_type=code&scope=non-expiring&consumer_key=MY_ID it redirects me back to my website? On localhost (dev API) it works.

Comment: Edit: think it's a bug, because I use .me domain.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the correct behaviour - once you've successfully authenticated, you should be redirected back to the `redirect_uri`. Is this working or not?